# Accessing Clipboard Object to Read Text in Javascript when window not Focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, clipboard, clipboarddata

I want to access clipboard object from `window.navigator` which is `window.navigator.clipboard` when window is blur or in background. I am unable to access on window blurred or background situation as clipboard object returns error for

> DOM exception: Document is not focused

How can I access clipboard when browser window is not focused or in blurred state?
I want to achieve this in web application.

1. Is it possible?
2. If it is not, then why?
3. If it is possible then how?
4. Can it be achieved in Some web worker or browser agent?

Comment: 2. – security / privacy reasons, most likely. I would not want any pages that I have not even currently focused, to be able to mess with my clipboard. Maybe I have some real sensitive data in there, like, say, a password, that I just wanted to copy&paste into the login form in the focused page A. If any page B lounging in the background would be able to _steal_ that password from my clipboard in that situation, that would of course be bad.

Comment: I like how I tried to find it out and being more confused before the question. [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) talks about an `navigator.permission.query` command and the [W3C Doc](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#permission-registry) says, there exists an `clipboard-read` but as i tried it, it tells me `TypeError: 'clipboard-read' (value of 'name' member of PermissionDescriptor) is not a valid value for enumeration PermissionName.`